# How to upload an image with a foreign key to a table using postman

Tags: spring, api, rest

Is there a way to upload an image to a table while using a foreign key at the same time? I know you can use form-data to upload the image, but how would you assign a foreign key's id to the post request?

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. Add code that you've tried, any documentation you've relied on, that looks like you've tried to fix a problem and failed. Your question is not very clear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assigned the primary key of the image to the other table instead